# SSL_accept hangs... sometimes ( C, linux, openssl )

Tags: c, linux, embedded, openssl

I'm currently working on an embedded linux system. There are two crucial client applications on the system that connect to an external server ( on another embedded system, all written in C ). The two apps use different certificates.

The ssl connection works... At least usually, but from time to time an error occures: the server hangs on SSL_accept() when accepting connection from one of the applications - the one using older certificates. Restarting the server application does not help, nor does restarting the client - the only way is to reboot the server system, unless I create a symbilic link to the new certificates used by the other app - only then will restarting the server app work.

Never does the error occur when both applications use the same, new certificate.

Could this happen due to some strange openssl cache or something like that?

Comment: Is there any data in one of the logs? What error do you get?

Comment: Are your underlying sockets blocking or nonblocking? If it is blocking, then the call won't return until the handshake has been completed.

Comment: It seems something to do with SSL lib programming. Is there any limitations on SSL lib? What kind of lib are u using? Opensource?